# When does the word “New” being removed from new item inside an announcement list, or document library

Tags: list, 2013, document-library, app

I have a document library and an announcement list,  now for any new item inside these lists a “New” word or symbol will be displayed for couple of days , then it will be cleared out.

So my question is for how long the "New" word will be displayed beside new items, and is this period configured somewhere?

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the value of days-to-show-new-icon/DaysToShowNewIndicator property, refer following:

- [NEW INDICATOR IN SHAREPOINT LISTS AND LIBRARIES – NUMBER OF DAYS TO SHOW](http://danmyhre.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/new-indicator-in-sharepoint-lists-and-libraries-number-of-days-to-show/)
- [Days-to-show-new-icon: Stsadm property (Windows SharePoint Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287681%28office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

By default, the "New" status indicator will display for 2 days; however, it can be configured - check out Salaudeen Rajack's SharePoint Diary entry at http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/new-tag-indicator-in-sharepoint.html.

Answer (score 0):

The following article has some additional info which maybe helpful.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/new-tag-indicator-in-sharepoint.html